how to check in twilio, which number will be used to send text from & to, i need it to be my number & not any random no., how to verify or change?
So i'm a bit new and i tried to do this tutorial but i'm confused about the trial number provided by the twilio and was wondering how can i change it, i have linked the video i was referring to
 #NodeJS and #Twilio to create an automated script which will send a message every hour using a CRON job. Basically i want to send someone automatic messages but from my number to their cell so how is it possible or am i doing something wrong, i referred this video but got stuck anyway
const cron = require('node-cron');

const config = require('./config');

const accountSid = config.Account_SID ;
const authToken = config.Auth_Token ;
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

const messages = require('./messages');

const currentMessage = 0;

function sendMessage() {

client.messages
    .create({
        body: messages[currentMessage],
        from: '+14849292367',
        to: config.twilio_phone_number
    })
    .then(message => {
        currentMessage++; console.log(message)
    .done();
    });
}

cron.schedule('2 * * * *', () => {
    console.log('message sent');
    sendMessage();
});

i put the twilio trial number given but there's no output and my terminal section just gives output of cronjob

This code has some syntax issues in the .then handler. Can you fix them? Also, do you see any message in the Message Log in the Twilio Console?
